# How should I organize my React Dispatch URLs

Tags: reactjs, react-router, redux-thunk, react-router-redux

The app I'm working on is using react-router-redux. Currently the way I handle link-clicking is I'll have the following:

```
clickEvent = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  this.props.dispatch(push(`/products/${product.id}`))
}
```

repeating itself in many different components. Same way applied to other links as well.

Recently we have decided to make changes to the url structure and suddenly I find myself searching for all `dispatch(push())` and fixing them one by one. So now I'm trying to find a way to store these urls in one single place.

The obvious and easy way I tried was by having a `routing_utils.js`:

```
import React        from "react"
import { push }  from "react-router-redux"

// Store all the possible urls here

export function visitHome(dispatch) {
  dispatch(push('/'))
}

export function visitProductShow(dispatch, productId) {
  dispatch(push(`/products/${productId}`))
}

export function visitProductReviews(dispatch, productId) {
  dispatch(push(`/products/${productId}`/reviews))
}
```

and then using it like so:

```
import { visitProductShow } from "../../routing_utils"

// ... inside a component:
  clickEvent = (e) => {
    const { dispatch, product } = this.props
    visitProductShow(dispatch, product.id)
  }
```

or you know, just store the urls without passing in `dispatch`, then call them like so: `dispatch(push(productShowLink(id)))`, either way it doesn't feel right.

Can this be handled through redux actions? If so, how can I go about it? I am looking for a better approach to handle this issue, thank you for your time.